# Windows PowerShell - Array to function

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have this problem which makes me crazy:

i have a function like

```
function xyz
{
    foreach($x in $input)
    {
    }
}

1..10 | xyz
```

this is saved in a file test.ps1. When I execute it like ".\test.ps1" every time it writes that

```
cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject[0]:
```

Why it is so? It does not work if I do like

```
$myArray = @("a","b","c")
xyz -arr $myArray
```

and doing a function like

```
function xyz
{
    param(
        [string[]]$arr
    )

    foreach($x in $arr)
    {
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: I did the code that you said prompted you for input and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: there was another error i just missed, the reason of that was that there was function in the function and in that function i wanted echo something, but there was just "echo" without the argument, i am from unix environment and when you type "echo" there without parameters, it just writes empty line and this trick does not work in PS ... what a stupid mistake :D

Comment: The answer selected does not answer the question. I came along with the same problem and was not helped by it. You have answered the question in your comment above, it would seem more appropriate to add that as an answer and select it.

Answer (score 5):

I can't duplicate the error you're seeing but in general, when you want to process pipeline input the easiest way is like this:

```
function xyz
{
    process {
        $_
    }
}

1..10 | xyz
```

The `process` block will get called for every object in the pipeline.  In fact, this is a common enough pattern that PowerShell has an even more convenient shortcut called a `filter` e.g.:

```
filter xyz
{
    $_
}

1..10 | xyz
```

Now if you need to handle regular parameters as well as pipeline input, then you need to add a param declaration and used advanced function parameter functionality e.g.:

```
function xyz
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [object[]]
        $myparam
    )
    process {
       foreach ($elem in $myparam)
       {
           $elem
       }
    }
}

xyz (1..10)
'a','b','c' | xyz
```

This works for both pipeline input and simple parameter (non-pipeline) usage.  This most closely emulates how binary cmdlets actually work.